# Angular empty option remove

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have problem with empty option when i repeat through array.
Here is code.

View:

```
<select  ng-model="getseason" class="form-control">
    <option  ng-repeat="season in seasons"  value="{{ season }}">
        Season {{ season + '/' + seasonaddone(season) }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Model:

```
$scope.getseason={};

$scope.seasons = [2014,2013,2012,2011,2010,2009,2008,2007,2006,2005];

$scope.getseason = $scope.seasons[0];

$scope.seasonaddone = function(season){
    return ++season;
}

$scope.$watch('getseason',function(){
    console.log($scope.getseason);
    console.log(typeof $scope.getseason);
});
```

How can i remove empty option?
I find many similiar problems, but i cant find solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of ngRepeat

Try like this

```
<select  ng-model="getseason" class="form-control" ng-options="season  as 'Season '+ season + '/' + seasonaddone(season)  for season in seasons">
</select>
```

Comment: Tnx,for ans. It work , but not exactly how i want.How can i change text between option tags? Value is ok.

Comment: `season as season` formate is `value as text` left side of as is value property and right of as is is text property.

Comment: So, in this way is not possible add additional text inside generated option tags?

Comment: i have updated my answer :) i hope this will cover your problem